# Kubernetes doesn't see istio gateway

Tags: kubernetes, istio-gateway

Steps:

1. run minikube
2. apply sample gateway  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.19/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml

   ```
   k apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.19/samples/bookinfo/networking/bookinfo-gateway.yaml
   ```
3. Try to get gateway

   ```
   k get gateway
   ```

[image]

**UPD:**

After restarting minikube, the gateway is created
[image]

Comment: Does the `k apply` returns something special ? Are you sure you've installed those resources within the `default` namespace ? Try to run `k get gateway -A` to be sure of the last one.

Comment: You could also run `k get virtualService -A` to check if this resources has been created.

Comment: @Irina , Let me know if the provided Answer was helpful. I am happy to assist you in case of any further queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the kubernetes version you are using as **Istio 1.19.0** is supported on **Kubernetes versions 1.25 to 1.28** as per the [**official documentation**](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.19.x/announcing-1.19/).

Also as per the **[Alibaba Cloud article](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/asm/support/why-are-no-gateways-or-non-istio-gateways-returned-when-i-run-the-kubectl-command-to-query-gateways)**, if you use Service Mesh (ASM) instances whose Istio version is 1.8.6 or later, you may encounter the issue `No resources found` as **Kubernetes Gateway API** is automatically installed in ASM instances.

> Both Kubernetes Gateway API and Istio API provide a resource that is named **Gateway**. The two Gateway resources have similar features, but they are different resources. The system cannot identify which resource that you specify when you run the command `kubectl get gateway`. As a result, Kubernetes gateways instead of Istio gateways may be returned. In this case, if no Kubernetes gateways are defined, no gateways are returned. You can also try with `kubectl get gateway --all-namespaces` to get gateway information in all namespaces.

To overcome this situation, you can follow the below steps.

- Use the ASM console to view Istio gateways.
- Use a full resource name or recognizable abbreviation in the kubectl command. For example, you can use **gtw** to represent **Kubernetes gateways**, and **gw** to represent **Istio gateways**.
- In this case, you can run `kubectl get gw` or `kubectl get gateways.networking.istio.io` to make sure that Istio gateways can be returned.

Comment: restarting minikube, now t works